# Opening links from Cordova app in external app - facebook, twitter or browser - both for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, twitter

Recently we upgraded our app to Cordova 6.0.0 and updated our iOS and Android platforms (to versions 4.1.0 and 5.1.1 respectively). Following this upgrade, old code we had to handle links stopped working.

We wanted to find out a way with which:

- links within our app to facebook will be opened in facebook app (if installed)
- links within our app to twitter will be opened in twitter app (if installed)
- other links will be opened in external browser and NOT within our app (safari/chrome)

We did not want to use the inappbrowser plugin (we actually tried it but it only gave partial solution, so we removed it). After spending some time on this issue we found the way to do it so we'll post the answer here hoping it will help any other developer who simply want links to open externally in the appropriate app.

Answer (score 1):

The following will demonstrate how we did it both in iOS and Android. You can replace SomethingCom with any other domain you'd like to be opened externally. Hopefully the examples will be self explained :-)

**iOS**

The place to do it is in the *shouldStartLoadWithRequest* function. As we found, the location of this function has changed in various Cordova versions, so the simplest way to find it is using xcode "find" and look for *shouldStartLoadWithRequest*. In the current versions (mentioned in the question) it is part of *CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m*.

```
(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

//START HERE: ADD THE FOLLOWING CODE TO OPEN LINKS
NSURL *url = [request URL];    

NSRange isFacebook = [[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"facebook.com"
                                                 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

NSRange isTwitter = [[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"twitter.com"
                                                options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

NSRange isSomethingCom = [[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"something.com"
                                               options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if(isFacebook.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSURL *fbAppurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/YOUR_PAGE_ID"];//Notice you need to replace YOUR_PAGE_ID with the ID number of your page

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbAppurl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbAppurl];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }

    return NO;
}
else if(isTwitter.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSURL *twitterAppurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?id=YOUR_USER_ID"];//Notice you need to replace YOUR_USER_ID with the ID number of your user

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twitterAppurl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitterAppurl];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }

    return NO;
}
else if(isSomethingCom.location != NSNotFound)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
}    
//END HERE 
...here comes the rest of this function which we left untouched
```

**Android**

The place we added the code is within our app Java class (under android > Java > com> our class package).

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import org.apache.cordova.engine.*;
public class MyClass extends CordovaActivity 
{
boolean isFacebookInstalled = false;
boolean isGooglePlusInstalled = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Check if facebook app is installed
    try {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                "com.facebook.katana", 0);
        isFacebookInstalled = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        isFacebookInstalled = false;
    }

    // Check if Google Plus app is installed
    try {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                "com.google.android.apps.plus", 0);
        isGooglePlusInstalled = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        isGooglePlusInstalled = false;
    }

    LOG.e("MyLog", "isFacebookInstalled = " + isFacebookInstalled + " ; isGooglePlusInstalled = " + isGooglePlusInstalled);

    init();
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.appView.getView();

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine) this.appView.getEngine()) {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            LOG.e("MyLog", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading = " + url);

            boolean isFacebook = (url.indexOf("facebook.com") != -1) ? true : false;
            boolean isGooglePlus = (url.indexOf("plus.google.com") != -1) ? true : false;
            boolean isGooglePlay = (url.indexOf("market://") != -1) ? true : false;
            boolean isSomethingCom = (url.indexOf("something.com") != -1) ? true : false;

            if (isFacebook) {
                if (isFacebookInstalled) {
                    url = "fb://page/YOUR_PAGE_ID";//Notice you need to replace YOUR_PAGE_ID with the ID number of your page
                }
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            } else if (isGooglePlus) {
                if (isGooglePlusInstalled) {
                    url = "https://plus.google.com/+YOUR_PAGE_NAME/posts";//Notice you need to replace YOUR_PAGE_NAME with the name of your page
                }
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            } else if (isGooglePlay || isSomethingCom) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }
    });

    loadUrl(launchUrl);
}}
```